# ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist

Tags: python, pip, pip-tools, pip-compile

I was creating a Python library, I needed to compile the pyproject.toml file.

I runned this command:

`pip-compile pyproject.toml --resolver=backtracking`

I got:

Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_wheel
Failed to parse .\pyproject.toml

My pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "filedump"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "Save multiple values to a .svf file (not encrypted)"
readme = "README.md"
authors = [{ name = "------", email = "-------------------" }]
license = { file = "LICENSE" }
classifiers = [
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
]
keywords = ["file", "encoding"]
requires-python = ">=3.9"

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = ["pip-tools"]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://github.com/-----------------------"

[project.scripts]
file = "filedump.FileOperation()"
```

My project root:

```
filedump\
|-- src\
|-- |___ __init__.py
|-- LICENSE
|-- MANIFEST.in
|-- pyproject.toml
|-- README.md
```

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/75533931/1529164

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean setup of pip-tools doesn't compile very basic pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75380003/clean-setup-of-pip-tools-doesnt-compile-very-basic-pyproject-toml)

Comment: The problem from that question (both comments point to the same question) relate to a faulty/missing version in the `project` section of the `pyproject.toml` . Looks like the same error message, different cause though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
[tools.setuptools]
packages = ["src"]
```

to your pyproject.toml
See [the following page](https://www.keithrpetersen.com/blog/pip-tools-pyproject-toml-setuptools/) for details, major thanks to Keith R. Petersen on this one :)