# Clean setup of pip-tools doesn't compile very basic pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip-tools

Using a completely new `pip-tools` setup always results in a `Backend subprocess exited` error.

`pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[project]
dependencies = [
  'openpyxl >= 3.0.9, < 4',
]
```

Running pip-tools in an empty directory that only contains the above pyproject.toml:

```bash
% python -m venv .venv
% source .venv/bin/activate
% python -m pip install pip-tools
% pip-compile -v -o requirements.txt --resolver=backtracking pyproject.toml
Creating venv isolated environment...
Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools >= 40.8.0, wheel)
Getting build dependencies for wheel...
Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_wheel
Failed to parse .../pyproject.toml
```

No `requirements.txt` gets created.

Ideas on what might be missing here are appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `pyproject.toml` most likely is invalid, try `pip install -e .` and you'll see a detailed explanation. For now, pip-tools can't show a nice error message, but [work is in progress](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/1711).

Comment: Thanks. Valid point as the respective `pyproject.toml` originates from using poetry, thus having dependencies listed in `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`. That doesn't fit pip-tools, which makes sense.

Comment: For completion: The error was in the `[project]` section of `pyproject.toml` missing a `version` entry, which seems to be mandatory. Using [validate-pyproject](https://pypi.org/project/validate-pyproject/) helps pointing this out.

Comment: I have started from the very minimal version and extending one line at a time until figure out what line causes the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64150719/how-to-write-a-minimally-working-pyproject-toml-file-that-can-install-packages